# How to generate Non Stationary time series data Using ARIMA.simulate()

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, arima

Have to generate non stationary time series data using different orders in ARIMA with the help of standard deviation.

I can able to generate Non stationary data but I am unable to do with ARIMA.simulate() in python ,kindly refer the statsmodel documentation.

For Reference:

https://rdrr.io/r/stats/arima.sim.html <-- this is for r language
https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.simulate.html <-- this is for python

I generated stationary data but i need to generate non stationary data by specifying the Coefficient and std.

The below code will generate the stationary data.But I need NON STATIONARY data.

```
modell=statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA((0,1,2))
series=modell.simulate(params=(0,1,2),nsimulations=100)
```

Comment: Check out this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473268/sampling-with-python-statsmodels-arima-package

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have to generate non stationary data using the coefficients and std in python.There are lot of examples in r language but i need in python